# Other than the Rutherford experiment, which experiments/proofs were used to prove that the atom is mostly empty space?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, atoms, subatomic

I know about Rutherford's gold foil experiment and his results which led him to believe that the atom is mostly empty space. Is there any other way in which this claim could be proven?

Comment: Well, technically this is not true as the atom has a electron cloud throughout which takes up all the space.

Comment: Electron scattering hee hee although the approach is similar haha

Comment: Perhaps better put, Rutherford (and don't forget Geiger and Marsden!) determined that (almost all of) the mass of an atom was contained in a small volume we now call the nucleus. Generally speaking, techniques to probe the nucleus are scattering experiments where you send something (ion, electron, photon) in and see what all comes out. Alpha particles just happened to be the available particle at the time for Geiger and Marsden. As noted above, there are electrons around most atoms (except for fully stripped ions).

Comment: @Sam 54 watch 00:00 to 00:31 from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3xLuZNKhlY

Comment: Depends what you mean by "empty." Nearly all of the _mass_ of an atom is concentrated in its tiny nucleus, but it's not the mass of atoms that define our macroscopic-scale experience of "solid" matter. Solids exist because electron interactions, and the electrons in solid matter effectively "fill" most of the space.

Comment: @user248881 Have you even seen the entire video that you just referenced?

Comment: What's wrong with Rutherford's experiment?

Comment: The main thing "wrong" with the Geiger-Marsden experiment (and more credit should be given to those "assistants" than to the mere director of the lab) was that they didn't have energetic enough sources to *measure* the size of the nucleus and had to settle for a upper limit.

Comment: @dmckee What I mean is, why does the OP want a different proof than Rutherford's?

Comment: If the OP is working from treatment found in a pop-sci source or one of the very short treatments found in introductory tomes they may have a very limited idea of what the analysis looked like and no real notion of how strongly it draws variaous conclusions. I don't think I *every* ready a real description of what the analysis can support in a textbook.

Comment: @dmckee - while I definitely agree that Geiger and Marsden often get slighted, Rutherford was the one to show mathematically that the Coulomb potential could account for the observed scattering. It took the group to bring the full (experiment+theory) together. (Geiger got his counter named after him, it really is Marsden who gets forgotten the most for what is probably the greatest contribution of an undergraduate to physics.)